# Java (log4j) deadlock on quad-core CPU. Why 300% CPU?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, deadlock

My Tomcat website hangs sporadically. When I dump stack traces I see up to 200 threads like this one:

```
"TP-Processor200" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fddf062a800 nid=0x4bce waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fdd5020b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007808d3a88> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
```

The java process then is consuming 300% CPU. I was expecting to see three threads in a RUNNING state, but I find none. Instead I find one for every logging message in BLOCKED state.

1. Why the 300% CPU? Is this a JVM thing to use up to number-of-core - 1 threads?
2. What can cause the deadlock? I am using the latest log4j.jar. The problem happens only with tomcat 6.0.35/java 1.6.0_31-b04, but not tomcat 6.0.18/java 1.6.0_17-b04

Thanks

Comment: I was probably blind and missed the three RUNNABLE threads. There were looping in a log4j Appender. I still wonder why there were exactly three threads every time...

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like deadlock for me: application utilizes all three cores completely.  Also it seems that application suffers lock contention in log4j, so most of the threads most of the time wait for log4j appender to be released by thread that is currently using it.